# Magento 2 Luma Theme, footers are not inside of page-wrapper on homeside

Tags: magento2, home-page

My new parent theme of magento 2 luma have problems with the "start page" (just the start / home page, the other pages are perfect).

The Elements footers, copyright.. are over the same position as page-wrapper, in all other pages like categorie view or product view the footers or copyright elements are inside the page-wrapper element.

This gives Problems with some Browsers.

***Not correct on the Homeside / Startpage***

[image: Not correct on the Homeside / Startpage]

***Correct on the Categorie Page***

[image: Correct, Categorie Side]

Anybody can help me to fix that?

Comment: What it affects? Your Frontend Layout in Different Browser? Check for the Content of that page which u have posted. Try to disable it. & clear cache

Comment: Bravo. Good to know ur issue is Solved :)